# Windows 8.1 Binding to app icon

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to display my app's icon (the one that shows up on the loading/splash screen) in my Win8.1 app, but can't figure out how I can bind to that resource in XAML. I'm looking to do something like: `<Image Source="{...}" />`. How would I bind to the icon resource?

Comment: This isn't a WPF question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Image Source="/Assets/SplashScreen.png" />`

It's not a binding though - simple string that gets converted into a URI and then a `BitmapImage` under the covers.